# how to install gcc-arm-none-eabi at Mojave MacOS

Tags: macos, gcc, arm, homebrew

i'm now using MacOS Mojave.

i want to use gcc-arm-none-eabi for ergodox. 
but i cannot install it by brew.

```
vikke@kosanji:~/vcswork/qmk_firmware
[master]$ brew search gcc-arm-none-eabi

No formula or cask found for "gcc-arm-none-eabi".
Closed pull requests:
gcc-arm-none-eabi 8-2019-q3-update (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/45780)
gcc-arm-embedded 9-2019-q4-major (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/46584)
WIP: arm-none-eabi-gcc 8-2018-q4-major (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/39869)
libelf: remove libelf and dependents (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/39871)
libelf 0.8.12 (downgrade to solve linkrot) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/39910)
Revert "Update gcc-arm-embedded to 6-2017-q1" (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/30433)
Update gcc-arm-embedded to 6_2-2016q4,20161216 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/28143)
arm-none-eabi-gcc 20150921 (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/45236)
Adding recipe for Pebble SDK 2.0-BETA5 (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/24834)
```

```
vikke@kosanji:~/vcswork/qmk_firmware
[master]$ brew install gcc-arm-none-eabi
Error: No available formula with the name "gcc-arm-none-eabi"
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

How to do it?

Comment: See: https://github.com/ARMmbed/homebrew-formulae

Answer (score 16):

If you got here looking for a way to install `arm-none-eabi-gcc` on macos, use the [ARMmbed brew formulae](https://github.com/ARMmbed/homebrew-formulae):

`brew install armmbed/formulae/arm-none-eabi-gcc`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Apple Silicon "bad CPU type in executable"

Comment: New versions Arm GCC toolchain are available from the gcc-arm-embedded cask, using the following instructions: `brew install --cask gcc-arm-embedded`

Answer (score 5):

i resolved.
download https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads and install.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew does not work all the time.  If you are on an older mac it is also likely that your operating system version is no longer supported by Homebrew.

So for people who are not having success with the other answers, Arm provide a proper signed macOS packaged version of the arm-none-eabi-gcc tool chain here

https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads

Comment: Using the Arm toolchain package on my older MacOS version as suggested solved the problem for me.

I got the error `arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'nosys.specs': No such file or directory` error on MacOS Big Sur (11.7.8) on my Mac (the latest supported OS on my machine) using the homebrew `arm-none-eabi-gcc` formula, but installing the packaged toolchain with `brew install --cask gcc-arm-embedded` solved the problem.